# Most efficient encoding of a point with X, Y into one unique number

Tags: python, encoding, coordinates

I am trying to make a function which converts 2D coordinates **(X, Y)** into one single number (Does not matter if integer or float), but what matters is speed because I need to call that function more than 50 times per frame and 60 frames a second. Which is a lot. Additionally the function can not mirror itself. What I mean by that is I need a different answer when using something like (10, 50) or (-10, -50).

Because with something like `x * y` and numbers **(10, 50)** the output is `500`, now when we change the numbers into opposite of that **(-10, -50)** the output is still `500` witch is not wanted.

But at the same time anything with exponencional growth is too slow, something like `2 ** x * (2 * y + 1)` ,even though it is not mirroring it has the problem of being too slow with large numbers **(100 000 and more)** and I would like to push that lag free zone as far as possible.

I hope I explained it clearly enough.

Comment: Shift coordinates until all (X,Y) values are nonnegative and then use quotient and remainder to get back from 1 number to 2, in which case `divmod()` is a very efficient decoder. This is essentially how a language like C stores 2-dimensional arrays as 1-dimensional arrays under the hood.

Comment: A complex number is a single, unique number `complex(x, y)`

Comment: What about bit operation like: (x << 32) | y, assume x and y can be stored in 32 bits. This is another implementation of what @JohnColeman said.

Comment: Why do you need to encode numbers this way?

Answer (score 1):

Python has infinite-precision integers, so you can encode this easily by using two ranges in the same integer.

First decide what precision you need. Lets say it’s 9.5 (up to 9 total digits with up to 5 digits after the decimal point), and the coordinate you need to encode is (107.13, 52.22).

You would first find the next-highest power of 2 greater than 10^9, which is 2^30.

You would then pad both the X and Y to 9 digits w/out decimal, so (10713000, 5222000).

Treating X as the lower-order part of the combined value, you would then add X to the up-shifted value of Y:

```
10713000 + (5222000 << 30)
```

You now have a big number that has Y in the upper bits and X in the lower with no possibility of overlap.

This is fast because it requires no multiplication, just a bit-shift. It might be a little faster to replace the `+` with a `|` (bitwise OR) since we know there are no bits overlapping.

How to decode the values out later is easy — two bit masks and a `>> 30` will do it.

You can deal with negatives by checking your range and using an offset. If valid values are +/- 9.5 precision, just add 999999999 to each value before encoding (so the lowest valid value maps to 0 and the highest valid value maps to 999999999 x 2, and up your bit-shift count by one:

```
(10713000 + 999999999) | ((5222000 + 999999999) << 31)
```

That’s with a couple extra parentheses to make it clear.

Comment: How would you deal with negative numbers?

Comment: This is a nice idea. You gloss over going from float to the padded-integer. Maybe it's obvious, but what's is an efficient way to do that? And you how do you get back —> how do you know 10713000 is 107.13 and not 10.713?

Comment: @MarkMeyer you have to know what the maximum and minimum precision was to decode it. This method does not record the precision in the number. Most compact encodings don’t carry information about the actual encoding. You just need to know what it is. If you’re handling both the encoding and decoding, that’s easy.

Comment: @MarkMeyer in this case I don't need to know if 10713000 is 107.13  or 10.713 all I need is the single number witch I am using as a seed for the random() function to get a float from 0 to 1 and based on that calculate if a planet should spawn in the cordinates (x, y)

Comment: Interesting @ErikKovac. I was asking about the implementation because I was curious about the efficiency. You can get an integer with `hash(complex(107.12, 52.22))`.  On my laptop that take a couple hundred nanoseconds. But I couldn't quite figure out how to implement the above to see how it compares. FWIW, a hash from a tuple of floats is also an integer and a bit faster .ie. `hash((107.12, 52.22))`

Comment: If you don’t need to decode the number, then clearly a hash is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply sort of compression technique as described [here](https://github.com/ajauhri/bignum_compression). Start from section 2 of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.05505.pdf).

Disclaimer -- I am one of the authors of the paper. Feel free to drop a line here if it seems like a good option for your problem, and you have any queries.